# Append pattern with NGINX rewrite rule

Tags: nginx

how can I append the `_clear` pattern at the NGINX request, as it is shown below:

```
/test/test.app/.umm/new=500-974652006

/test/test_clear.app/.umm/new=500-974652006
```

thank you.

Comment: Try `rewrite ^/test/test\.app/(.*) /test/test_clear.app/$1;`

Comment: if I have multiple names for test, what is needed for the rewrite?

Comment: I can't guess what names you talking about. You need to be familiar with regular expressions to write an appropriate regex pattern.

Comment: I tried the following, but it seems that nginx cannot catch the any uri: 

    location / {
        if ($request_uri ~* "(.*)\.app(.*)") { set $proxyurl 'http://backend/$1_clear.app/$2'; }
        proxy_pass $proxyurl;
 }

any other clues?